# Extend $T$ to a bounded linear operator...

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be the real inner product space of real-valued continuous functions on $[0,2\pi]$ with the standard inner product. Consider the map $T:X \to H$, where $H=L^2[0,2\pi]$ (the completion of $X$), defined by

$$Tx = \int_0^{2\pi}cos(t-s)x(s)ds.$$

Also, keep in mind that $(1/\sqrt{2\pi},\cos(t)/\sqrt{\pi},\sin(t)/\sqrt{\pi},\cos(2t)/\sqrt{\pi},\sin(2t)/\sqrt{\pi},\dots)$ is a total orthonormal sequence in $H$.

1. Prove that $T$ is a bounded linear operator.
2. Extend $T$ to a bounded linear operator $T^*:H \to H$.

I have already shown part (1). I am not sure how to proceed with part (2). I know there are Theorems that say that we can extend bounded linear operators, but I am not seeing how to use them.

Comment: I apologize if I am missing something, but isn't the expression for $T$ perfectly well-defined even for arbitrary $x \in L^2[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: @Klaus yes, but I think they're being specifically asked to work with extensions. You don't always know you have the right domain, after all. :P

Comment: That's clear from context, right? For the extension to even work we need $T^*x = Tx$ for every $x \in X$. Any suggestions on how to proceed?